# Can I Insert an entire array in other array position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an array called *arr1* and a second array called *arr2*. Both are created dinamically (I mean arr2 is different every time enters a while and arr1 it's the same but is filled everytime by arr2 new array).

I want every postion of *arr1* to have an different array (in the example arr2 is always the same but nevermind that), how can I do this?

I've tried this way:

```
//Some context
arr1[x] = new Array();
arr2[y] = new Array();
while(j < 10){
  arr2[j] = j;
  j++;
}
while(x < 10){
  arr1[x] = [arr2]; //problem
  x++;
}


arr1[x] = new Array(otherArr.length);

arr1[x] = [arr2]  (?)

arr1[x] = arr2 (?)

arr1[x] = new Array(arr2.length)
arr1[x] = arr2 (?)
```

Comment: Do you really want arr2 to be at every position or just copies of arr2 to be at every position. Think carefully, they are different things.

Comment: You want to arr2 to be accesible using all indexes of arr1? Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for showing us what you have tried. It would be helpful if you would show us what sort of code you want to work. For example, after you perform this 'magic', will you then modify `arr2` and expect `arr1` to be changed? Are you talking about a two-dimensional array, or just equality? _What are you trying to do?_

Comment: I've edit the question. Please, take a look.

Comment: I want every postion of arr1 to have an different array

Comment: @Bagata Then see my answer, as the answers of Lukas and opensourcechris will both use the same `arr2` array in all positions of `arr1`, and any modifications to such an array will affect all (as shown at the end of my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
  arr1[i] = arr2;
```

Edit: use
    `for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
      arr1[i] = arr2.slice(0);`
If you want to copy the array instead of using a reference.

Comment: This assumes that you wanted a pseudo-two-dimensional array as the result, where you can then use `arr1[3][7]` to get one of the eighth items of `arr2`. However, it also means that any modification to any value in one column will affect others. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want every postion of arr1 to have an independent array;

Answer (score 1):

If array1 has length > 0 then you can use this method to replace each position in array1 with array2.

> ```
> array1 = ["","",""]
> array2 = [1,2,3]
>
> for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
>   {
>   array1[i] = array2;
>   }
> ```

Comment: The length doesn't have to be > 0. Your loop just doesn't get executed when it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use `arr2` as a template, such that later modifications to one 'row' don't affect others:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [4,5,6];

for (var i=arr1.length;i--;) arr1[i] = arr2.concat(); // create a copy
```

At this point you have the equivalent of:

```
var arr1 = [
  [4,5,6],
  [4,5,6],
  [4,5,6]
];
```

…such that you can change `arr1[0][0] = 0` and see:

```
[
  [0,5,6],
  [4,5,6],
  [4,5,6]
]
```

instead of

```
[
  [0,5,6],
  [0,5,6],
  [0,5,6]
]
```

as some other answers here will cause.